# iOS - Labels or Images

Tags: ios

In my app I have a textfield that users start typing into and below the textfield a tableview appears with suggestions that they can click on to auto complete. When they click on it I want to add it as a "tag" below which they can click on again to remove, just like how tags work on here when you write a question.

My question is should this "tag" be a Label that is styled or should I create images and add those to the screen instead?

Comment: Why not make it a UIButton?

Comment: Decision depends on control design requirements. If it is simple text then use UILabel, if it something custom then you could use UIImageView + UILabel or UIButton.

Comment: I'd recommend creating a custom UIControl for it so you can customize it as you wish with maybe a label, and a button on the right side with 'x'

Answer (score 0):

Images should be avoided whenever possible.

I would personally subclass UILabel and take over the drawing to create a box effect or similar.

Remember to test your app with Voice Over whenever you create custom views.